# Iterating (Looping) through columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, filter

I am struggling in R and hope that someone can help me out. I am trying to write a for loop to iterate over the columns of a data frame, but unfortunately, I am not successful.

So here is my Problem:
I have 10 data frames (dt1, dt2 ,dt3,…,dt10). For example, dt1 looks like this:

```
dt1<-data.frame(Topic1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),Topic2=c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), Topic3=c(1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5), Name=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
```

I want to check if the Name variable still contains “A” and “B” when I filter I filter Topic 1 (then Topic 2, Topic3…) to greater than 5. At the moment, I do the following

```
Library(dpylr)

dt.new<-dt1 %>% filter(Topic1>5)
isTRUE("A" %in% dt.new$Name && "B" %in% dt.new$Name)
```

At the end of the day, for each data frame, I want to have a new table (data frame) that looks like this:

```
result<-data.frame(Topic=c("Topic1","Topic2","Topic3"),Return=c("FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"))
```

Now the problem is, that I have several data frames (dt1, dt2…) each of them has more than 50 variables (Topic1,…, Topic50).

I've written some loops so far and tried it out. But unfortunately without success. Therefore I would be happy to receive any hint or tip.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'Name', `summarise` the variable that have column names that start with 'Topic' by checking if there are `any` value that are greater than 5, then `gather` (getting deprecated - in the newer `tidyr` - use `pivot_longer`) to convert from 'wide' to 'long', grouped by 'Topic' column, `summarise` by checking if `all` the 'val' elements are TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt1 %>%
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Topic')), ~ any(. > 5)) %>%
    gather(Topic, val, -Name) %>% 
    group_by(Topic) %>% 
    summarise(Return = all(val))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Topic  Return
#  <chr>  <lgl> 
#1 Topic1 FALSE 
#2 Topic2 FALSE 
#3 Topic3 TRUE
```

---

Or reshape it to 'long' format first and then do the `summarise`ation

```
dt1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Name, names_to = "Topic") %>%
   filter(value > 5) %>% 
   group_by(Topic) %>% 
   summarise(result = n_distinct(Name) == 2)
```